# Consider infinity in codomain of rational function if field is algebraically closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Example 2.3.4 on pg. 43 of *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* by Qing Liu, it says

> If $k$ is algebraically closed, we can consider a rational function as a function $k \rightarrow k \cup \{+\infty\}$.

Why is it important that the field be algebraically closed?

Comment: This has to do with the fact that if $k$ is not algebraically closed, the residue fields of the points of $\operatorname{Spec} k$ corresponding to irreducible polynomials of deg > 1 will be the splitting fields of such polynomials, not $k$.

Comment: and sections on an open set are determined by their values in the residue fields

Comment: Well actually I'm positive they are determined by values in the local rings, that's just the fact that 'equality' is a local property. I'm pretty sure about the claim of the fields as well but I don't have a reference.

Comment: @basket You need some assumptions about reducedness. If $f \in A$ vanishes at all residue fields, it means that $f \in Nil(A)$, since $Nil(A)$ is the intersection of all primes. But if you are reduced then $Nil(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is the concrete problem that if $k$ is a finite field, there are only finitely many functions from $k \to k \cup {\infty}$, while the field $k(t)$ of rational functions is infinite. So the identification doesn't make sense, because it is not injective.

Requiring to work over an algebraically closed field is one way to fix this problem, though you can also be content with an infinite efield. Generally the philosophy is that if your base field is not algebraically closed, you have secret points that are seen from a finite extension of your base field. What is a $L$ point in $Spec A$ but a map $A \to L$? Take $A = \mathbb{Q}[t]$ and you will get points over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (and the evaluation of $f(t)$ at this point is just $f(\sqrt{2})$ or $f(-\sqrt{2})$? Brain teaser.)... but still a function $f \in A$ is determined by $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

(The hint for why infinite fields work is that if a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $k[t]$ has $n + 1$ zeros in $k$, then it is the zero polynomial.)